# How to use Javascript variable in the value portion of a JSON?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

```
var avg_temp = req.params.rating;
var destination = req.params.name;


var temp = { "results.name" : destination }; 


var wew =  {$set: {"results.$.rating" :avg_temp} }; 


mach.update(temp ,wew , function(err,jop){
                if(err)
                {
                    res.status(500);
                    res.send('Destination not found');
                }
                else
                {
                    res.status(202);
                    res.send('Rating is posted');
                }
            });
```

Sample document :

```
{
      "_id" :    ObjectId("56247581846ec164bb6be7bf"),
        "results" : [ 
        `enter code here`{
            "name" : "Mk.Mechanics",
            "ph" : NumberLong(9899991817),
            "error" : false,
            "lat" : 28.5833958899999980,
            "lon" : 77.1687398899999980,
            "rating" : 3,
            "add" : "1123, Nanak pura, Delhi, 110021, India",
            "local" : "Nanak pura",
            "city" : "Delhi",
            "contry" : "India"
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "Pahadi",
            "ph" : NumberLong(9876591817),
            "error" : false,
            "lat" : 28.6776553099999990,
            "lon" : 77.2616931799999950,
            "rating" : 3.5000000000000000,
            "add" : "plot-6 saranshpur, Shastri park,Delhi,110018, India",
            "local" : "saranshpur",
            "city" : "Delhi",
            "contry" : "India"
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "mirza",
            "ph" : 1.23123e+007,
            "error" : false,
            "lat" : 28.6775564800000000,
            "lon" : 77.2621437899999960,
            "rating" : 1,
            "add" : " plopur, Shastri park, Delhi,110099,India",
            "local" : "Shastri park",
            "city" : "Delhi",
            "contry" : "India"
        }
] }
```

### Heading

When i use static value in destination and avg_temp (eg. "Pahadi" and 12 respectively) this works but in this case it does not

Request is a patch request which I am making to the Node server :

```
localhost:8000\api\machs?name=Pahadi&rating=1
```

Any idea How to access JavaScript object in json

Output : Destination Not Found (Eventhough i've put exact string values in name params)

Comment: Please try formatting your code and explain your issue instead of posting code with comments.

Comment: u can use parse , like ->
 var json = JSON.parse(temp);, check this -> http://www.mkyong.com/javascript/how-to-access-json-object-in-javascript/

Comment: Why are you stringifying your JSON??

Comment: Sorry , im new here . I hope the data which i've giver now is sufficient and the format is comfortable too .

Comment: @Anirudh I guess JSON.parse is to convert JSON to a Javascript object whereas in my case i would like to use the value inside my Javascript variable inside a JSON document .

Comment: yeah u want u use javascript variable as json object right ?

Comment: did u check that link, is that not what u wanted ?

Comment: No thats not what i want :( , thanks for help though

Answer (score 0):

just put a `console.log(err);` above `res.status(500);`. So that we can know what the error is from DB.

Answer (score 0):

Ahh Silly Mistake , Changed req.params to req.query as the values were sent by the http request in query string ! Problem solved , Now the code works as it should . Thank you guys for participating though :)